# Jq strftime() to show time in a specific time zone

Tags: jq, strftime

How to use jq to convert seconds since Unix epoch to a time string in human readable format but adjusted to Sydney, Australia time zone?

I tried filter:

```
now | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

But I don't know how to adjust the time format string to convey Sydney, Australia time zone.

Possibly I need to replace "Z" with the relevant time zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the following convert to the time zone indicated by the `TZ` environment variable var:

```
localtime | strftime(...)
```

```
strflocaltime(...)
```

For example,

```
$ jq -nr 'now | strftime("%FT%T")'
2022-02-14T06:14:07

$ jq -nr 'now | gmtime | strftime("%FT%T")'
2022-02-14T06:14:07

$ jq -nr 'now | localtime | strftime("%FT%T")'
2022-02-14T02:14:07

$ jq -nr 'now | strflocaltime("%FT%T")'
2022-02-14T02:14:07
```

That uses your local time, as determined by `TZ` environment variable. Adjust as needed.

```
$ TZ=America/Halifax jq -nr 'now | strflocaltime("%FT%T")'
2022-02-14T02:14:07

$ TZ=America/Toronto jq -nr 'now | strflocaltime("%FT%T")'
2022-02-14T01:14:07

$ TZ=America/Vancouver jq -nr 'now | strflocaltime("%FT%T")'
2022-02-14T22:14:07
```

If you want to convert to different time zones in a single run of `jq`, you're out of luck. `jq` doesn't support converting to/from time zones other than UTC and this time zone.

Tested with both 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: Unfortunately, localtime does not work in Debian Buster (10.6) which has `jq` version "jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe". `| gmtime |` works, but not the "localtime" versions. It works fine in Ubuntu 20.04 with jq version "1.6".

Comment: gmtime does not give localtime, they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jq v1.6, use `strflocaltime` instead of `strftime` which displays the time in **your** timezone.

```sh
jq -n 'now | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/84uwwDuEKJ)

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Dates):

> The `strftime(fmt)` builtin formats a time (GMT) with the given format. The `strflocaltime` does the same, but using the local timezone setting.

If your timezone is different, set the shell's `TZ` variable accordingly before calling `jq`

```sh
TZ=Australia/Sydney jq -n 'now | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")'
```

Comment: Thx for your help. For me time is not adjusted even when I try TZ=Australia/Sydney or TZ=UTC+11.

Comment: @LoganLee Did you put a `;` between `TZ=…` and `jq -n …`? Because there shouldn't be any (otherwise you'd have to use the `export` command).

Comment: no I didn't put ; after TZ=...

Comment: @LoganLee And using `strflocaltime` doesn't show a difference to using `strftime`?

Comment: strflocaltime works correctly.

Comment: @LoganLee Hm, I'm sorry, I'm at my wits' end.